# Определить регион адресов в сегменте данных

Tags: c++

Например есть код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
int region1_start = 0;
 
int val1 = 0x55;
 
int val2 = 0x66;
 
int region1_end = 0;
 
int main(void)
{
 
    //размер региона в байтах
    int size = (char*)&region1_end - (char*)&region1_start;
 
    //просто какие то вычисления с переменными из региона
    int ret = val1 + val2;
 
    //выводим размер региона в байтах
    printf("%X\n", size);
 
    return 0;
}
```

Что мне надо - что бы в сегменте данных ЕХЕ файла была такая последовательноть (например 0х0 начало сегмента данных - для примера):

0x0000 region1_start //смещение 0 байт
0x0004 val1 //смещение 4 байт
0x0008 val2 //смещение 8 байт
0x000C region1_end //смещение 12 байт

Есть такие то директивы компилятора или настройки Visual Studio что бы мне сделать такой регион памяти и int size было = 12?

То есть мне важна последовательность данных в сегменте данных сначала region1_start потом val1 потом за ней в сегменте данных val2 потом конец моих переменных region1_end.

Я просто скомпилировал код С++ выше, и посмотрел дизасемблером - компилятор С++ раскидал все 4 переменные по разным участкам сегмента данных. Мне нужна именно такая последовательность как я указал. Фактически мне надо пометить блок данных в сегменте данных.

Как это сделать? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Используйте структуру.

Comment: Это мне нужно для компилятора WATCOM. Может быть есть какой то способ именно в этом компиляторе? Структура мне не подходит.

Comment: @black4 А чем вас структура не устраивает? ну сделайте статический массив на стеке, но не факт что компилятор это не оптимизирует (хотя это юб, так что не должен)